Third party js only executes on paths with one parameter in React.js
I transformed a HTML,CSS,JS template to a react app. I copied asset folder in template and pasted it in public folder of my project, then imported js and css files in head of my index.html. like this:
    <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/vendor/waypoints.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


it works fine when I open a route with one parameter or less, like: localhost:3000/param1 or localhost:3000/ . but when I assign a path with more than one parameter, it does not work. like: localhost/param1/param2. here is my router:
const routes=[
    {path:'/', element:<Static></Static>,
    children:[
        {path:'/', element:<Index></Index>},
        {path:'/blog/:catId', element:<Blog></Blog>},
        {path:'/grid/:catId', element:<BlogGrid></BlogGrid>},
        {path:'/blogdetails/:subId', element:<BlogDetails></BlogDetails>}
        ]
    }
]

and in my app.js, I import useRoutes and routes and then inside function App(){}:
  const router=useRoutes(routes)
  //some useEffect stuff here//
  return <>
    {router}
  </>

I also am ok with a solution that runs the js codes on every route change or in useEffect of component that gets rendered on route change, but I can not get it to work. I also looked here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/3256 but it did not understand much.

This is likely an issue caused by using relative source paths. Try using absolute paths, e.g. paths starting with "/" or fully qualified source URLs.
Examples:
<script src="/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/vendor/waypoints.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>

<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/vendor/waypoints.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/bootstrap-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/main.js"></script>


I guess it does have something to do with paths, but when I give it absolute path from root directory of project ( or even root of my hard drive, if it is supposed to work) it does not fix the problem, and makes it worse, since now it does not run on localhost:300/ as well. here is my path now, starting from my react project: /shofy-react/public/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js. when I click on it in my IDE, it does open the js files correctly, but the js is not applied to my page. - even in starting route "localhost:300/" -

@benyamin It likely should be an absolute path from the root of the public folder that is deployed, so "/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js" seems to me to be the correct path based on the information provided. When you use the relative path "assets/js/vendor/jquery.js" what is the request URL when it works?

this: "/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js" does not work, saying the js file was not found. But I did fix the problem with: "%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js". the js was was supposed to be at: localhost:3000/assets/js/etc but when you loaded website on other paths it went to localhost:3000/some_path/assets/js/etc and could not find the js.
